# Lefschetz number in terms of Poincaré dual and fundamental class

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

We define the Lefschetz number as $L(f)=\sum_n (-1)^n \text{Trace}(f^*\colon H^n(M)\rightarrow H^n(M))$

I want to show that the Lefschetz number can be written as $L(f)=\langle\Delta^*(u_{\Gamma}),[M]\rangle$. Where $\Delta\colon M\rightarrow M\times M $ is the diagonal map, $\Gamma$ is the graph of $f$, $u_{\Gamma}$ is the Poincaré dual of $\Gamma$, and $[M]$ is the fundamental class of $M$. But I am not sure how to compute $\langle\Delta^*(u_{\Gamma}),[M]\rangle$.